# PHP After submit check if Data input was sent, and if its less than 3 characters give error

Tags: php, html, post, input

How can i check if this **form input** was sent to this PHP page and if it's longer than 3 characters? If it's less than 3 characters, I want to print an error.

Form

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="formFlow">
    <label for="name" >Name:</label>
    <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" class="border"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$var = $_POST["name"];
if (!empty($var) || strlen($var >= 3)) {
    echo "Yes, name is sent";    
}else{  
    echo "Error, name short";
}
?>
```

Comment: seems there is a mistake in the condition ``strlen($var >= 3)`` must be ``strlen($var) >= 3``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem

```
<?php
$var = isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : "";
if (!empty($var) && strlen($var) >= 3) {
    echo "Yes, name is sent";    
} else {  
    echo "Error, name short";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not use OR operator in your condition becuase it will always true either length of string less than 3 or greater than.

You must need to use && operator.

Second you have an issue in [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) it must need a string not condition.

**Example**:

```
if (!empty($var) && strlen($var) >= 3) {
```

Comment: `$var = $_POST["name"];
 if (strlen($var) >= 3) {
    echo "Yes, name is sent";    
    }else{  
    echo "Error, name short";
}`  I think i did a mistake , is this good ? Thank you

Comment: @bogdan-laza both r fine... Or if u use isset()  this will more good.